# Haskell equivalent of Boost.Fusion

Tags: haskell, boost-fusion

I have been playing with creating a fully typed DSEL in Haskell using GADTs and such for a fully type-safe AST, and it seems that doing a correctly typed compiler requires constructs such as maps from Haskell types to both types and values (typed environments) and such that can be understood by the Haskell type system.  C++ has the Boost.Fusion library with constructs like these (type->value maps, vectors of typed values, etc.).  Data.Tuple takes care of sequences, but are there Haskell versions of things like Boost.Fusion `map`s?

Comment: What was the reason for the downvote?

Comment: When you describe a "compiler" what representation are you compiling from/to? If you have the GADT, are you really writing the interpreter for it, or a function from the GADT to, e.g., C code?

Comment: Either -- the same issues will come up in anything that translates the typed AST to anything else or runs it.

Comment: yea why the downvotes? seems like a fine question to me..

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- this is perhaps not the forum, but I don't think the issue comes up as much as you'd imagine? However, take a look at this: http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/index.html#tc-GADT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the [dependent-map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-map) package. I haven't used it myself, but it seems to do what you're asking for. If you need to really use type (and type-only) equality then you may need to agree on a default value or use a `TypeRep` as the key instead.

Answer (score 4):

First, the all-too-obvious answer is that you can easily write a "type->value map" using `Typeable` (part of base library):

```
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Map

type TypeMap a = Map TypeRep a

insertT :: Typeable k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a
insertT v = insert (typeOf k)

lookupT :: Typeable k => k -> a -> Map k a -> Map k a
lookupT v = lookup (typeOf k)
```

Now you can use code like `insertT (undefined :: Int) 5` to insert elements by type.

But looking at Fusion, this doesn't really look like what you might be after. It seems it allows you to build code working on arbitrary data structures? That is something that in Haskell is known as "Scrap your Boilerplate" generic programming. See the [papers](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/) or [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) for details, but it allows you to write code that processes arbitrary data structures and picks out values of given types.

A few other things that I saw of Fusion could probably be emulated using libraries such as [HList](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/) or possibly [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels). But it's *really* hard to say more without a look at what you actually need.

Comment: Your `TypeMap` will work but requires an `unsafeCoerce` to convince the compiler that the type on the right side matches the `TypeRep` on the left (or `Data.Dynamic`).  HList looks interesting as well; fclabels looks more like it provides zippers.  I don't need reflection/data-generic programming over arbitrary data types, so I don't think SYB would help.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure whether or not you wanted the value in question to have its index type. If you want that, you probably either should use `HList` (if you know the keys of your map statically) or a similar map construction using `Dynamic` in the values to get around `unsafeCoerce`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned previously, `dependent-map` seems like the right choice for the map side of things, but I'd recommend looking at the [`HArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HList/0.2.3/doc/html/Data-HList-HArray.html) interface of `hlist` as an alternative to manually juggling tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Data.Map](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html), and lists? (e.g. `[Int]`).

Comment: No, since the elements need to have different types, and here the keys are types.  I would like something that does a mapping like `(Int->5, Float->"foo")` in a value (not a type class that gives a global mapping).  I know how to write it by hand (I think), but I was wondering if somebody did it already.

Comment: @NathanHowell: Could you please post this as an answer?  I'll check it out, but it looks from the documentation like it's what I'm asking for.